# Problem installing pysbrl on windows 10 with python 3.7/3.6

Tags: python-3.x, windows, github, pip

I have been trying to install pysbrl. I have used

```
pip install pysbrl
```

but that also gets error while creating wheel.
Then I tried

```
pip install pysbrl --no-binary=pysbrl
```

That did not solve the problem either. 
I am using python 3.7. Also tried with python 3.6.

I am getting the below error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\T2020\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\T2020\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7t3xs1dx\pysbrl\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\Users\T2020\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7t3xs1dx\pysbrl\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\T2020\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-skjwp8mt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\T2020\Anaconda3\Include\pysbrl'
cwd: C:\Users\T2020\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7t3xs1dx\pysbrl
Complete output (23 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pysbrl
copying pysbrl\discretize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pysbrl
copying pysbrl\rule_list.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pysbrl
copying pysbrl\sbrl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pysbrl
copying pysbrl\train.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pysbrl
copying pysbrl\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pysbrl
copying pysbrl_init_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pysbrl
running build_ext
building '_sbrl' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\c
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\swig
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -Ic/ -IC:\Users\T2020\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\T2020\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\T2020\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcc/pysbrl.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\c/pysbrl.obj -std=c99
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
pysbrl.c
C:\Users\T2020\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7t3xs1dx\pysbrl\c\rule.h(33): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gsl/gsl_matrix.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\T2020\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\T2020\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7t3xs1dx\pysbrl\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\Users\T2020\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7t3xs1dx\pysbrl\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\T2020\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-skjwp8mt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\T2020\Anaconda3\Include\pysbrl' Check the logs for full command output.
[this should also explain why the current behaviour is a problem and why the
expected output is a better solution.]
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev`

Comment: I have mentioned that I am using windows. Sudo is not for windows.

Comment: As the error says, you need to install GSL as a prerequisite for using the package. Looking at the [Github repo](https://github.com/myaooo/pysbrl) for this package, it looks like you'll need both GSL and GMP. Both can be installed using [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/index.html).

Comment: I have installed GSL and GMP both.